# sed script for duplicating the line ON that same line

Tags: sed

I want to take a line and duplicate what is on that line.

E.g.

```
line1
line2
line3
...
```

I want to end up with:

```
line1 line1
line2 line2
line3 line3
..
```

I was trying this, but this didn't do it.

```
sed -e 's/^$1 $1//' FILE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
sed 's/.*/& &/' FILE
```

or

```
paste -d " " FILE FILE
```

Comment: Just for fun, we can combine sed and paste: `sed p FILE | paste -d " " - -`

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the matched string, so you want

```
sed -e 's/.*/&&/' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$0=$0" "$0' file
sed 's/.*/& &/' file
```

Comment: `'{print $0,$0}'` might be less word for awk.

Comment: @glennjackman I don't agree with you. `$0=$0" "$0` len=10; but your `{print $0,$0}` len=13; `13 > 10 == true`

Comment: Typo, I meant "less work". I wasn't thinking about code golf. Your script has to reconstruct $0 and then print it, while mine just prints. Of course, the real difference I'm sure is miniscule